# Deutscher bestimmte Artikel auf schwedische Flußnamen?

Tags: article, place-name

Flüsse haben auf Deutsch immer einen bestimmten Artikel, auch nichtdeutsche Flüsse. Was passiert aber wenn ein einheimischer Name, wie auf Schwedisch, schon einen hintergestellten bestimmten Artikel hat? Nehmen wir z.B. Dalälven, einen großen Fluss in Mittelschweden, dessen Namen "*der* Talfluss" bedeutet.

Würde man sagen:

> Ich gehe im Dalälven baden?

Dalälven hat ja schon den bestimmten Artikel und ein von den Artikeln ist also redundant. Es dürfte richtiger heißen:

> Ich gehe im Dalälv baden

oder

> Ich gehe in Dalälven baden

Was aber (wohl) nicht richtig gut auf Deutsch klingt?

Comment: Ich hätte mit "älv" immer den männlichen Artikel verwendet: "im Dalälv(en)". Ansonsten schliesse ich mich @Uwe an.

Comment: Und insbesondere den Dativ: "Ich gehe im Rhein (in der Donau, im Eisbach) baden".

Comment: Also "im Dalälven" wäre richtig wenn ich alles verstanden habe.Ich editiere meine Frage demnach. Warum eigentlich Dativ? Ich gehe ja beim Baden ins Wasser. ?

Comment: Offenbar denkt die Sprache so: Du gehst zum Fluß, und dann gehst zu zwar in den Fluss (wohin? Akkusativ) hinein, aber dann bist du drin im Fluss (wo? Dativ), und dein Baden findet dann stationär dort im Fluß (wo? Dativ!) statt. (Nein, den Scherz mit "Warum im Fluß? Weil es da tief ist" mache ich jetzt nicht.) Du kannst allerdings *an den Fluß baden gehen*, aber das ist "an den Fluß gehen [zum] baden".

Comment: Ist der Artikel im Schwedischen in diesem Fall nicht ein Teil des Eigennamens? Im Deutschen ist der Artikel bei Flüssen, Bergen usw. jedenfalls obligatorisch, man kann ihn nicht weglassen. Und den schwedischen Artikel kann man auch nicht weglassen, wenn's ein Eigenname ist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bei der Übernahme eines fremdsprachlichen Wortes (das gilt nicht nur
für Namen) ins Deutsche spielt die Grammatik der Fremdsprache typischerweise
keine Rolle. Die einzigen Ausnahmen sind manche Pluralformen
und ein paar biblische Namen (Genitiv "Jesu Christi").
Das bedeutet: Daß "-en" im Schwedischen ein Artikel ist, ist
dem deutschen Muttersprachler meist nicht bewußt,
und selbst wenn er es weiß, klingt es für ihn ohne deutschen Artikel falsch.
Darum geht "in Dalälven" nicht. Ob man ein skandinavisches Wort
mit oder ohne skandinavischen Artikel importiert, ist Geschmackssache;
bei einigen Namen (z.B. norw. "Lofoten") ist aber die Form
mit Artikel allgemein üblich.

Die Frage stellt sich übrigens nicht nur bei skandinavischen Namen. Ein bekanntes Beispiel aus Kalifornien: Mitten in Los Angeles befinden
sich die La Brea Tar Pits (wörtlich "die der Teer Teergruben").

Comment: Ein ähnliches Problem gibt es bei manchen afrikanischen Sprachen, wo man vor der Frage steht, ob das Klassenpräfix mit übernommen werden soll. Z.B. heißt es heutzutage meist "Swahili", früher sagte man im Deutschen "Kisuaheli" (mit Klassenpräfix ki-, das eine Sache anzeigt).